# why jdbc throw data truncation exception when sqlstate startwith 22

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector

why JDBC transform sqlstate to 22001 when receive sqlstate start with 22 such as 22005 ?

```
if (xOpen != null && xOpen.startsWith("22")) {
                    throw new MysqlDataTruncation(errorBuf.toString(), 0, true, false, 0, 0, errno);
            } else {
                    throw SQLError.createSQLException(errorBuf.toString(), xOpen, errno, false, getExceptionInterceptor(), this.connection);
            }
```

code in MysqlIo.java

Who konws why?